# How will the #line compiler directive in F# be used in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

Will the Visual Studio debugger display the F# source or the source being referenced by the #line directive or the F# source? Any drawbacks? (for instance, I assume that neat tricks like mousing over a declaration will stop working as the original source will not be parsed?)

#### EDIT:

It was suggested to me that I'm just being lazy. This is of course very true. I tested it and answered my own question.

Comment: You have a point ;-) I know people have used it for parser generators and as code generation is much work, and I can imagine that debugging is impaired to some degree. 

So in my defense, I was also asking for any drawbacks to this approach. Building code generators are much work, so I'd rather ask what to expect before going down that route.

Comment: Can't you just write a 10-line program with #line directives to try it?  I expect either that it works, or it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Stepping works as expected
- Break points works as expected
- VS does some probabilistic assumptions. For instance, you can right click on an identifier to inspect it ("hey, I have no idea what exotic grammar this guy uses, but I'll bet you that he uses whitespace, operators and identifiers in a common enough way, let's help out").
- However, VS is not bold enough to make the same probabilistic assumption on mouse over (it does not inspect).

Drawbacks:
 - VS seems to do some highlighting of statements that does not work well if the original code is very different from the generated F# code. Strange behavior I would think?